# Polynomials and ideal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ and field $n$ positive integer. Let $g$ element $F[t]$ given by $g (t) = t ^ {n}$. Show that $g$ generates the ideal $J$ of $F [t]$ consisting of all polynomials of degree greater than or equal to $n$.

Could someone help me?

Thanks, I am sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: As stated this seems to be false as $\,F[t]\,$ is a principal ring and thus the ideal generated by $\,t^n\,$ is all the multiples of this polynomial, which then will have zero as a zero of multiplicity $\,n\,$...but there are plynomials with arbitrarily large degree which do *not* have zero as one of their roots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is not true under the usual definition of degree (the exponent of the highest order term).  Perhaps you mean that $J$ should consist of all polynomials whose *lowest* order term is greater than or equal to $n$.  In that case, the proof is pretty immediate from writing out that condition explicitly.

Comment: This is not answer but an explanation, but + 1 because it is a rather good one.